# 2ГИС Конструктор карт в React

Tags: html, reactjs

Чтобы импортировать карту дан код

```
<iframe id="map_694258809" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="600px" sandbox="allow-modals allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(e,t){var r=document.getElementById(e);r.contentWindow.document.open(),r.contentWindow.document.write(atob(t)),r.contentWindow.document.close()})("map_694258809", "длинный код")</script>
```

Вставляя этот код в в простой html, все работает, но как вставить его в react компонент

```
import React from "react";
const Map = () => {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
  )
}
export default Map;
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте что то вроде этого

```
const Map = () => {
  const id = 'map_694258809';
  const txt = 'длинный код';
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.contentWindow.document.open();
    ref.contentWindow.document.write(atob(txt));
    ref.contentWindow.document.close();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <iframe ref={ref} id={id} frameBorder="0" width="100%" height="600px"
              sandbox="allow-modals allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation"></iframe>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Map;
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<iframe id="map_21958526" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="600px" sandbox="allow-modals allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation"></iframe><script type="text/javascript">(function(e,t){var r=document.getElementById(e);r.contentWindow.document.open(),r.contentWindow.document.write(atob(t)),r.contentWindow.document.close()})("map_21958526", "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")</script>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]